# Xcode-Cannot create new project

Tags: xcode, project

I recently switched computers (from an iMac to a new Mac Mini), and I just finished transferring my keychain information, developer profiles, etc. I went to File > New > Project, entered in a quick name, and noticed that the "Next Button" does not work (it looks completely gray, as if it weren't enabled). I double-checked that all my information was entered, but still nothing.

I feel like the answer is completely obvious, so thanks for any help!

UPDATE: Here is a link to the screenshot:
http://s1337.beta.photobucket.com/user/znichols1131/media/ScreenShot2013-01-23at72110PM_zps0af03a90.png.html

SOLUTION: I went back to my old computer, tried to create a new project, and it worked. So I took a closer look at the New Project screen on my old computer and copied the information onto my new computer. It looks like I either forgot the company identifier (like in the screenshot) or I typed in a weird one. Thanks for all the help and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Share some more details? A screenshot maybe?

Comment: Stack Overflow won't let me because I'm a new member and I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: Upload the screenshot to another website and link it then?

Comment: What website would you suggest?

Comment: Try something like http://imgur.com