# Xcode won't let me create a new project

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to create a new project but it won't let me proceed to to the next window after I have named my project and selected the language. I have attached screenshots.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZMuj.jpg

As you see in the last picture it won't let me go "Next". I think that's the window where I'm suppose to save the project into a folder. Please help me solve this problem. I am new to Xcode. Thanks.

EDIT: I can create files and workspaces but whenever I create projects this happens.

Comment: whith version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Comment: This guy seems to be having a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491857/xcode-cannot-create-new-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: run this code in the terminal

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

It will reset all xcode settings.

Comment: I've never seen this issue myself. But surely this question-answer is going to be useful to someone some day! Well done. In a couple of days you can even accept your own answer, and you should.

Comment: Thanks you. Yes this is a pretty rare issue. At first I tried manually deleting com.apple.dt.Xcode but that did not work. When I tried deleting it through the terminal it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Happened to me with Xcode 13. Thank you!